# Parentheses in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `Product_Category` in my table and it contains values like:

```
'Fit', 'Tight', 'Wide', 'Tall','Short', 'Thin'
```

I have another column called `Product_number` with values:

```
'1234','1235','1236','1237','1238','1324','1325'
```

In my query, I have a `where` clause and I want to ensure that my parenthesis is right. Here is the where clause below:

```
where (Product_Category= 'Fit'
       and Product_number IN ('1234','1235','1236','1237','1238'))
   or (Product_Category in ('Tight', 'Wide') and Product_number= '1324')
   or (Product_Category in ('Tall', 'Short', 'Thin') and Product_number = '1325')
```

Are my parenthesis (bracket) in order?

Edit: added an apostrophe.

Comment: There's definately problems with that code. You should have noticed when in SSMS (and you'll also see now that your code is formatted as code) that you have an unclosed quotation in there. As for your question, we don't actually know what your goal for your logic is, so we can't actually tell you.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu, initially you had a missing ' - however you need to be mindful of the precedence between OR and AND - however your selections appear to be plausible - you do have some redundant brackets

Comment: It looks like someone edited your erroneous SQL for you, that's ok, but surely it'd be best to point it out as a comment/answer?  It did sound like that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
where (Product_Category = 'Fit' and  Product_number IN (1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238)) or
      (Product_Category in ('Tight', 'Wide') and Product_number = 1324) or
      (Product_Category in ('Tall', 'Short', 'Thin') and Product_number = 1325)
```

You can see if the parentheses balance more easily if the code lines up.

Importantly, I assume that `product_number` is a number.  Compare it to numbers.  Type conversions can adversely affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

not quite

```
select 0 
    where (Product_Category= 'Fit' and Product_number IN ('1234',1235','1236','1237','1238')) or (Product_Category in ('Tight', 'Wide') and Product_number= '1324') or (Product_Category in ('Tall', 'Short', 'Thin') and Product_number= '1325')
```

gives

```
 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')
```

'.

so

```
select 0 
where (Product_Category= 'Fit' and Product_number IN ('1234','1235','1236','1237','1238')) or (Product_Category in ('Tight', 'Wide') and Product_number= '1324') or (Product_Category in ('Tall', 'Short', 'Thin') and Product_number= '1325')
```

is then ok

note

```
    '1234',1235'
```

is in vaLID, it would probably be '1234','1235', but you could have '1234',1235' by typing '1234'',1235' to 'escape' the rouge quote - that's what SQL doesn't know if you mean or not

--you don't need all the parantheses - AND takes Priority over OR and IN is a single TRUE/FALSE operation - extra parantheses are not really harmful though

```
where Product_Category= 'Fit' and Product_number IN ('1234','1235','1236','1237','1238')
     or Product_Category in ('Tight', 'Wide') and Product_number= '1324'
     or Product_Category in ('Tall', 'Short', 'Thin') and Product_number =   '1325'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but i do not see the difference in what in your response. Can you spot tell me where the difference is?

Comment: you say IN ('1234','1235','1236','1237','1238')) - but when i copied it there was a missing ' character!  hold on I'll check - yes you added that in, other than that, nothing seemed wrong, although check other posts regarding numbers/strings comments